# Calculate daily increase/decrease in COVID-19 cases / deaths

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, excel-2016

I was trying to plot some reports for Covid-19 cases around the Globe, using Excel and Power BI. With Power BI is easier and fancier to do definitely, but I need an Excel file or calculation that makes sense - similar to the PBI. What I actually wanted is to calculate the daily increase in new cases (with %) and also death rate but per day, or total death by day and so on..

I did some calculations (% of column total and I calculated one field to get death rate%)  here using Pivot tables but not sure how to do daily increase/decrease? Did anyone get an idea for additional calculations?
This is copied from PBI (calculations) which I wanna have similar in Excel - but I am not sure If I can calculate it properly (last 2 pictures).

The data source from the input data is here:

https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide.xlsx

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question rather than screenshots of the code. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: "but I need an Excel file or calculation that makes sense" what does this mean?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid means that I need calculations that are in Excel and not in PowerBI as you can see 2x Pictures (copied from PBI calculations). I asked similar calculations but only in Excel, cuz the calculation is different.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra column for the result you want (e.g. daily increase/decrease), then you can plot either the waterfall chart, or using techniques similar to 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5945-excel-chart-display-percentage-change.html

Comment: thx, but I wasn't quite clear with my issues. I added more pictures. I know I can do it with additional columns...but I wanted to know complete calculation similar to one above =))

Comment: It really depends on how you want to show the figures.  As an example, if you need to show the daily case increase/decrease, you just need to construct your pivot table by 1) put the date field as Rows and 'Ungroup' it to show individual date, 2) put the "cases" to the value field and set "Show value as" % of previous in Field Settings, 3) add whatever slicer(filters) you need as in your screen capture. Then, you are good to plot whatever graph you need. No additional formula is needed.